# Yii cdbcriteria select a relation's columns

Tags: php, yii

I am having very difficult time to select usernames of all posts in the blog demo given in Yii..

author is relation of post class with user...

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with='author';
$criteria->select='author.username';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
));
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
```

**Error:**

Active record "Post" is trying to select an invalid column "author.username". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what `with` does is `eager loading`..that means the relation's data
>   will also loaded from database alongwith, and when when u'll call the
>   relation, there won't be a actual query..
>
> What select does is it selects it from database and maps it to model
>   variable..

Now in your case what is happening is you're trying to write some relation's column in select, which will be there in select even without writing it, **but as there is no corresponding variable to map this value yii is throwing an error..**

So first thing if you need to username of auther in response, you can get it by relation calling, which won't be a database call, and u dont need to write a select..

And if u want to call the username as a part of the post model only **u have got to declare it as a property in model, and then specify alias in select..**

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with='author';
$criteria->select='author.username as auther_username';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
));
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
```

> and in your Post model declare..

```
public $auther_username;
```

Now it won't throw error, and you can access the username by both ways..`$post->auther_username`, and `$post->auther->username`

Comment: i'm not accusing, but if you downvoted, please explain why? because i don't see anything wrong in my method,(neither in yours).

Comment: so, it seems this is what op was looking for, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array('author'=>array('select'=>'username'));

// you can still select Post table columns here
$criteria->select='post_content';

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
   'criteria' => $criteria,
));
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
```

Comment: same as in? the criteria is working for sure. let me know what line of code is giving you the same result.

Comment: someone upvoted a few days back! then someone downvoted some hours back! so downvoter, if you read this, please explain your reason, because there is nothing wrong in my code, and in my method. maybe i can improve the answer, if need be. constructive criticism is always welcome

Comment: for yr downvote...if u notice what the user is asking for `select usernames of all posts`..which he can obviously anyway get with the relation call $post->user->username, all `with` helps is that it makes it eager-loading..so now that means what user needs is to get the username, without calling the relation, in the same var_dump he wants it, which your answer doesn't provide at all..

Comment: now lets talk about what your answer provides..what it says is put select in with itself, which has no relevance in this case..it actually means that while loading author relation's data, only load column called username..which by the way is a error-free code, but he still can't get username without calling the relation..which he could've done even without doing the select thing...and u dont explain why the error is happening..so in short what yr answer provides is a way to not have error, and not have what is needed as well..now I hope that explains itself..

Comment: first of all thank you for the reply, most people don't comment/reply when asked about downvoting. now to reply, if that is the way, you understood the question, then i see your point, and also the point to your answer. however let me explain my answer, first asker has not mentioned anywhere **how** he/she wants to access the username, so i made no assumption of that. second to select only username of the author, instead of passing author.username in the select of dbcriteria, we can pass it in criteria of the relation in `with`, which is what my answer does.

Comment: i asked the op 'same as in?' in the comment of feb 26 9:09, to which i received no clarification, so what should i do? how could i have done anything else to provide a better answer, if the asker doesn't reply

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array('author'=>array('select'=>'username'));
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
));
var_dump($dataProvider->getData());
```

Source: [CActiveRecord.with](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail)

> In order to customize the options on the fly, we should pass an array
>   parameter to the with() method. The array keys are relation names, and
>   the array values are the corresponding query options.