# Yii CDBCriteria LEFT JOIN not working

Tags: php, yii

I have a `CDBCriteria` here:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('t.lastname', 't.name', 't.patronomic', 't.dob', 'n.nationality', 't.token', 'm.status');
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN hrp_nationalities n ON (n.id = t.nationality_id) ';
$criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN hrp_marital_status m ON m.id = t.marital_status_id';
$criteria->condition = "t.`alive` = 1 AND t.`org_id` = ".$_SESSION['org_id'];
$criteria->order = 't.id DESC';
```

My question is why `m.status` and `n.nationality` are not retrieved into the resulting object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the CDbCriteria on a model class eg `$results = User::model()->findAll($criteria);` then the result will contain only fields from user table, not the relations'. The reason is that when the resultant model objects are created there is no field declared for the relation columns in the model.. So you need to create fields in the model..

in your case `nationality`, `status`

Just write in your model

```
public $nationality;
public $status;
```

**And if your model also has a field named `status`, use an alias for the relation's field `status`..**

```
public $m_status;
$criteria->select = array('t.lastname', 't.name', 't.patronomic', 't.dob', 'n.nationality', 't.token', 'm.status as m_status');
```

I just remember I have answered an old similar question.. Read answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11594530/1114536